# Go back to previous position when coming out of quickfix

Tags: quickfix, navigation

When I navigate out of the quickfix list, the split I get put back in is not the same as the one I left.

For example:

1. `vim -u NONE`
2. `:copen` open quickfix list
3. <kbd>^w w</kbd> leave quickfix list
4. `:vsplit` open a split
5. <kbd>^w l</kbd> go to right split
6. <kbd>^w j</kbd> go to quickfix list
7. <kbd>^w k</kbd> leave quickfix

I expect this to bring me back to the right split,
since that's where I was when I entered the quickfix list,
but instead it brings me to the left split.
Is there any way to change that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The window command `p` (as in `<C-w>p` or `:wincmd p`) takes you back to the previous window.

Comment: How did I not know about `<C-w>p`? Thank you! Do you happen to know the name of the option to change that? Or the help it's in?

Comment: Maybe `:help botright` or similar (you might need single quotes)? @Marcel

Comment: afaik there is no such option. There is `:botright`, `:belowright`, `'splitbelow'`, and similar, but those are for _creating_ splits, not moving between splits

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your cursor position in the previous window (prior to switching windows with `^wk` or similar).

From `:h ^wk` (emphasis mine):

> Move cursor to Nth window above current one.  **Uses the cursor
> position to select between alternatives.**

So, if the cursor is on the right of the quickfix window, `^wk` will bring you to the right split. Otherwise, the left split is chosen.

(A quick way to move to the far right of the window is `$`, or `g$` if the line wraps around, though I think you know that already)